# Настройка шаблонов в Eclipse/Netbeans, как в IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, netbeans, intellij-idea

Добрый день, комьюнити! 
Вчера меня взяли на работу Java программистом (мой первый опыт). До этого я всегда разрабатывал в IDEA, но работодатель сказал выбираться между eclipse и netbeans. Открыв эти среды я ужаснулся, там нет нормального автодополнения. Те например в IDEA я пишу psvm - и она мне генерирует public static void main метод, или sout и это будет System.out.println и т.д.

Я уверен, что не один с такой проблемой, может подскажите какие-то плагины, которые могли бы из Eclipse/Netbean сделать мою любимую IDEA? Заранее ОЧЕНЬ благодарен.

Comment: gedit попробуйте...

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь это не плагин, а просто текстовый редактор. Те вы предлагаете писать код в нём и копировать в IDE?

Comment: На сколько понимаю работодатель не хочет покупать IDEA, и предлагает бесплатные вариант, но в большинстве случаев за глаза хватает комьюнити версии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates -> New:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого в коде пишите `psvm` и нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Есть плагин Recommend а так же templates, например если вбить syso, это равносильно sout в IDEA.

Comment: Я думаю, уместно сослаться на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953818/automatic-text-expansion-in-eclipse , там картинка и указание, где что настраивать.

Answer (score 1):

Templates для кода на любом языке есть в любой IDE, только в разных IDE они по-разному называются, например вместо `psvm`в IDEA, в Eclipse надо набрать `main`, вместо `sout` надо набрать `sysout`. Вы можете заучить новые названия, либо настроить всё это под себя как вам нравится. См. [Getting started with Eclipse code templates](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-code-templates/). В хелпе есть перечень переменных, доступных для использования в шаблонах [Java Editor Template Variables](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-editor-templates.htm).